# Retrieve error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED from firebaseio.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase ERR_NAME_RESOLVED]

[Network Firebase Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrO1P.png)

Hi, I got some problem with firebase realtime database. When I try my firebase configuration (prod) on local or staging (same server as production), it's not show this error. But when I deploy it to production, error occurs when I try hit firebaseio.com. Can someone explain it?
The server I use is AWS CloudFront (staging and production).

Firebase I use is here https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase with Vue 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshots there's an additional `%27%2C` after `firebaseio.com` in the URL, which is not supposed to be there. So it looks like you have a `',` in the database URL that you initialize Firebase with, which are not supposed to be there. Remove those and this problem should disappear.

Comment: Ah, yeah, when I check the configuration, there a comma after some configuration. Thank you for the answer!